# Determine parent-parent template in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a problem that I need a little changes in template depending on parent-parent template. In this example template `PhysicalPerson` is Ok if parent template is `Debtor` but not if `Claimant`. And all the difference is that Name is required in one but not in another, as well link
 `<a class="UserDataButton" style="float:right; padding:2px 2px 0 0;">Insert my data</a>` I need in first but don't in second.

Is it even possible to determine if tag belongs to specific parent-parent template? Or I need different approach?

```
<xsl:template match="t:Debtor">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-Debtor" data-tab-name="Debtor">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="t:PhysicalPerson" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="t:LegalPerson" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="t:AddressList" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="t:PhoneList" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="t:EmailList" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="t:Claimant">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-Claimant" data-tab-name="Claimant">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="t:PhysicalPerson" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="t:LegalPerson" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="t:AddressList" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="t:PhoneList" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="t:EmailList" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="t:PhysicalPerson">
    <div>
      <div class="fiz_persona">
        <div style="float:left; padding:2px 0 0 2px;">
          Physical Person
        </div>
        <a class="UserDataButton" style="float:right; padding:2px 2px 0 0;">
          Insert my data
        </a>
        <br />
        <label class="floatleft required"><span class="star">*</span>
          Name
        </label>
        ...................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `<xsl:template match="t:Debtor/t:PhysicalPerson">` then the template is only applied to `t:PhysicalPerson` elements having `t:Debtor` parent element. You can then write another template `<xsl:template match="t:Claimant/t:PhysicalPerson">...</xsl:template>`.

Comment: I was hoping that there is a different way without copy-paste entire template and edit just a few lines. But this solution works as expected, thanks!

Comment: The main saving I see is with the first two templates which could be merged to do `<xsl:template match="t:Debtor | t:Claimant"><div class="tab-pane" id="tab-{local-name()}" data-tab-name="{local-name()}">...</div></xsl:template>`. For the `<xsl:template match="t:PhysicalPerson">`, you could move the code needed only in one case to a separate template `<xsl:template match="t:PhysicalPerson" mode="debtor"><a ...>...</a><label ...>Name</label></xsl:template>` and then do `<xsl:if test="parent::t:Debtor"><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="debtor"/></xsl:if>`.

Comment: That means - all differences has to be together (if I have different  only 3, 10 and 18 code line then new template will not be the solution). But thanks anyway - probably I'll use this later! :)